# CSS combine class attribute and not() selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I want to select all elements that contain a part of a certain class ("action-"), while simultaneously not containing another class ("button").

```
<a href="#" class="action-delete"></a>
```

I thought this would work:

```
a[class*='action-']:not(.button)
```

Which means: select all a-tags that:

- a) have a class starting with "action-" AND
- b) don't have class "button"

However this only works in safari, and is completely ignored in chrome/chromium/edge/firefox.

It does seem to work if I change it to excluding *type* button, instead of class button. Which makes me think the problem may be that I am using both an attribute selector and a direct one to target the class? But no idea how to fix this.

Comment: works on chrome

Comment: Your code is valid and works on chromium / edge / firefox.

Comment: Okay thanks for verifying. Then it must be other stuff floating around the codebase that ruin things.

Comment: * means 'contains', **^** is 'starts with...' may/may not be a crucial difference. Check out [w3schools: CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: @RenevanderLende I know, thank you. What I meant is it contains a class (so *) and that class itself starts with "action-". But indeed, not relevant here.

Comment: Be aware that with a (*) some class like `prefix-action-postfix` will be selected too...it's in the details.